# Spring Integration DSL : Send messages to multiple subscribers (not to all subscribers) based on the message payload

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have to create a pipeline to send messages to multiple subscribers, I can achieve this using publishSubscribeChannel.

But in my case when I receive the message - I have a eventSubType like

```
<ns1:eventSubType>0:INIT-SHIP-ASSIGN,BKD,</ns1:eventSubType>
```

I have to check if the eventSubType Contains INIT-SHIP-ASSIGN then I will route it o "INIT-SHIP-ASSIGN" channel and if its "BKD" then I have to route it to "Booked" channel. Similarly we have other eventSubTypes.

My challenge is - I have 5 different subtypes and in each message we can have multiple subtypes. So, based on the event subtypes (can be more than 1) available in the message, we have to send the message to the multiple subscribers but not to all the subscribers.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use a [recipient list router](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers) instead.

```java
.routeToRecipients(r -> r
        .recipient("thing1-channel", "'thing1' == payload")
        .recipientMessageSelector("thing2-channel", m ->
                m.getHeaders().containsKey("recipient")
                        && (boolean) m.getHeaders().get("recipient"))
        ...
```